# Find if array can be divided into two subarrays of equal sum if any one element can be deleted

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sub-array

Given a array of numbers find if there is a way to delete/remove a number from the array and make one partition in the array( dividing the array into two subarrays ) such that sum of elements in subarray1 is equal to sum of elements in subarray2.

```
A subarray is a contiguous part of array.
Array [1, 2, 3, 4] has (1), (1,2), (2,3,4),(1,2,3,4) etc.. as its subarrays but not (1,3) , (2,4) , (1,3,4), etc..
```

Now let us consider one example:-

```
(Follow 0-based indexing )
Array[] = [ 6, 2, 2, 1, 3 ]

Possible solutions
Delete Array[0] => updated array: - [ 2,2,1,3 ]
Possible partition              : - [2,2] and [3,1] where (2+2) = (3+1) = 4
or
Delete Array[1] => updated array: - [ 6,2,1,3 ]
Possible partition              : - [6] and [2,1,3] where (6) = (2+1+3) = 6
or
Delete Array[2] => updated array: - [ 6,2,1,3 ]
Possible partition              : - [6] and [2,1,3] where (6) = (2+1+3) = 6
```

Now a similar question already exists where we just have to, find if array can be divided into two subarrays of equal sum , can be done in O(n) =>

> PsuedoCode:- The efficient solution involves calculating sum of all
> elements of the array in advance. Then for each element of the array,
> we can calculate its right sum in O(1) time by using total sum of the
> array elements minus sum of elements found so far. The time complexity
> of this solution would be O(n) and auxiliary space used by it will be
> O(1).

So to solve our problem one brute force method is:- remove every element once and check if the array can be divided into two subarrays of equal sum. Thus it will require O(n^2) time.

So can we do better than this time complexity?

Comment: Where is the pivot and what is the answer for input, [10, -1, 1]? In other words, can one side of the partition be empty of elements?

Comment: Both the partition must contain at least one element. So for your example no pivot will exist and we can return -1...Just wondering even if we could keep any one partition zero the 'optimal approach' for original question can be modified to accommodate that, is'nt it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map to keep track of the position at which each value in the array occurs. Then, as you move through the array considering each partition point, if the difference between the left and right halves is present in the map, and in the correct half (determined by comparing whether the left-right difference is positive or negative with the position of the value relative to the current partition point) then you have a solution.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static boolean splitDelete(int[] a)
{
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        List<Integer> idx = map.get(a[i]);
        if(idx == null) map.put(a[i], idx = new ArrayList<>());
        idx.add(i);
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(int v : a) sum += v;
            
    int diff = sum;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
    {
        diff -= 2*a[i];
        if(map.containsKey(Math.abs(diff)))
            for(int j : map.get(Math.abs(diff)))
                if(diff > 0 == j > i) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I added an answer that I think is similar to yours, except it doesn't store indexes for the seen elements. What would be the complexity of your answer for an input where the `for(int j` loop was O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

As RaffleBuffle [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684164/find-if-array-can-be-divided-into-two-subarrays-of-equal-sum-if-any-one-element#comment121388402_68685319), there could be a few scenarios for the deleted element as we traverse different separation points. For example,

```
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
<-----X--------->|<------->

a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
<--------------->|<---X--->
```

One way to solve it with O(n) overall complexity, could be to traverse twice. Each time checking if the difference between the two sums is in a map of values we've been tracking for the side we came from.

Python code:

```py
def f(A):
  values = set()
  total_sum = sum(A)

  # Traverse from left, each part
  # must have at least one element.
  left_sum = A[0]
  right_sum = total_sum - A[0]
  values.add(A[0])

  for i in range(1, len(A) - 1):
    values.add(A[i])
    left_sum += A[i]
    right_sum -= A[i]

    # We have an element in the left part
    # that's the difference between left
    # and right sums.
    if (left_sum - right_sum) in values:
      return True

  # Traverse from right, each part
  # must have at least one element.
  right_sum = A[len(A)-1]
  left_sum = total_sum - A[len(A)-1]
  values.clear()
  values.add(A[len(A)-1])

  for i in range(len(A) - 2, 0, -1):
    values.add(A[i])
    right_sum += A[i]
    left_sum -= A[i]

    # We have an element in the right part
    # that's the difference between right
    # and left sums.
    if (right_sum - left_sum) in values:
      return True

  return False

As = [
  [1, 2, 1, 1, 1], # True
  [1, 1, 1, 2, 1], # True
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], # False
  [6, 2, 2, 1, 3]  # True
]

for A in As:
  print("%s\n%s\n\n" % (A, f(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

So when an element is removed from the array, there could be two cases where the pivot can be formed.

1. The pivot is formed to the left of the deletion
2. The pivot is formed to the right of the deletion

In either case we have to find whether the new array can be partitioned into sub arrays whose sums are equal.

let `newSum = (sum-nums[i])/2`

**Case-1:**
both newSum and `2*newSum+nums[i]` should exist in the prefixSums

**Case-2:**
both `newSum+nums[i]` `2*newSum+nums[i]` should exist in the prefixSums

Answer (score 0):

I've taken inspiration with גלעד ברקן's code and I think you can do it in one pass. Here's the modified Python code. We can just check if we've seen the absolute value of the number that we've seen before. I think it will work for negative numbers in the array too, but feel free to point out inputs that will break this code.

```py
def f(nums):
  seen = set()
  total = sum(nums)
  prefix = 0
  for num in nums:
    prefix += nums[i]
    seen.add(nums[i])
    if abs(total - prefix * 2) in seen:
        return True
  return False
```